# Are the face posets of CW-complexes Eulerian?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, order-theory

Suppose we had a CW-complex $X$ with decomposition $X_{i}$

Is its face poset, consisting of cells and covers generated by the attachment of cells to one another, an Eulerian poset? What would be the most concise method of proving this?

If not can we prove that; there are at most two $y$ such that $y$ covers $x$ and $z$ covers $y$?

EDIT: Can we ensure that either of these conditions by restricting to regular CW-complexes?

Comment: I don't know the precise definition of the face poset of a CW complex, but it seems to me that the standard CW decomposition of $D^2$ as a CW complex with one cell in each dimension is a counterexample: one cell of odd dimension, two cells of even dimension.

Comment: Ok many thanks. I guess a more precises definition would be that for each open cell $C$ we have that $D \leq C$ if $\partial C$ intersects $D$.